# VBA: assign dynamic array in user object definition

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, types

I have this definitions:

```
Type Linea
    name As String
    color As Long
End Type

Type lineas
    from As Integer
    to As Integer
    lineas() As Linea
End Type
```

How could I instantiate a "lineas" variable assigning several lines on the fly like this pseudocode in proper VBA code?

```
Sub colours()
    Dim lineas_CMTS As lineas

    lineas_CMTS.from = 200
    lineas_CMTS.to = 219
    lineas_CMTS.lineas() = New Linea {name="Cisco", color=RGB(0,50,100)}
    lineas_CMTS.lineas() = New Linea {name="Huawei", color=RGB(50,0,100)}

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no syntactic shortcut.  Using a class with a backing array you could LineA.AddLine(a, b, c) otherwise the best you can do is helper functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alex K said, there's no way with those two structures as you wrote them

but you could consider a workaround, substituting the `Linea` Type with an `Array`

```
Type lineas
    from As Integer
    to As Integer
    lineas() As Variant ' use a variant type instead of a "Linea" one
End Type

Sub colours()
    Dim lineas_CMTS As lineas

    With lineas_CMTS
        .from = 200
        .to = 219
        ReDim .lineas(0 To 1) 
        .lineas(0) = Array("Cisco", RGB(0, 50, 100))
        .lineas(1) = Array("Huawei", RGB(50, 0, 100))
    End With
End Sub
```

you could avoid `ReDim .lineas(0 To 1)` if you already know `lineas()` array dimension in advance

```
Type lineas
    from As Integer
    to As Integer
    lineas(0 To 1) As Variant
End Type


Sub colours()
    Dim lineas_CMTS As lineas

    With lineas_CMTS
        .from = 200
        .to = 219
        .lineas(0) = Array("Cisco", RGB(0, 50, 100))
        .lineas(1) = Array("Huawei", RGB(50, 0, 100))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to define two classes and to refer to them. Class `LineaCollection` holding a collection of the class `Linea`. Thus, you may refer to them in a module like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lineasCMTS As New LineasCollection

    lineasCMTS.From = 200
    lineasCMTS.ToV = 219

    lineasCMTS.AddValue RGB(0, 50, 100), "Cisco"
    lineasCMTS.AddValue RGB(0, 50, 101), "Huawei"

    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = 1 To lineasCMTS.InfoCollection.Count
        Debug.Print lineasCMTS.InfoCollection(cnt).Name
        Debug.Print lineasCMTS.InfoCollection(cnt).Color
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

The idea of these classes, is that Linea has the `Name` and the `Color` properties, including a [factory design patter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for creating itself:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_sName As String
Private m_lColor As Long

Public Property Get Name() As String    
    Name = m_sName    
End Property

Public Property Get Color() As Long    
    Color = m_lColor    
End Property

Public Property Let Color(ByVal lNewValue As Long)    
    m_lColor = lNewValue    
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal sNewValue As String)    
    m_sName = sNewValue    
End Property

Public Sub CreateLinea(newObj As Linea, newColor As Long, newName As String)        
    newObj.Name = newName
    newObj.Color = newColor        
End Sub
```

The `LineasCollection` has the `AddValue`, `AddToCollection` methods, which communicate with the `Linea` class or with the module outside. `From` and `To` are properties and `InfoCollection` is the possibility to access the whole collection:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_lFrom             As Long
Private m_lTov              As Long
Private m_cLineasCollection As New Collection

Public Property Get InfoCollection() As Collection
    Set InfoCollection = m_cLineasCollection
End Property

Public Property Get From() As Long
    From = m_lFrom
End Property

Public Property Get ToV() As Long
    ToV = m_lTov
End Property

Public Property Let ToV(ByVal lNewValue As Long)
    m_lTov = lNewValue
End Property

Public Property Let From(ByVal lNewValue As Long)
    m_lFrom = lNewValue
End Property

Public Sub AddToCollection(newObj As Linea)
    m_cLineasCollection.Add newObj
End Sub

Public Sub AddValue(colorNew As Long, nameNew As String)
    Dim newObj  As New Linea
    newObj.CreateLinea newObj, colorNew, nameNew
    AddToCollection newObj
End Sub
```